# Get the Outlook Mail Count by Sender Name

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-2007, office-addins

I am developing an Outlook 2007 Add-in in C#, where I need to count the number oif mails a particular sender has sent ?

For example, person A has sent 5 mails, person B has sent 10 mails & person C has sent 15 Mails. How can I get this count for every member ?

I can write this logic of my own as well using a `Dictionary<String, Int32>`, but when this sender list becomes big, It will be a HUGE performance hit.
Is there any predefined property for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If it´s an outlook add-in, then all the e-mails in the sent folder is sent from the user of the mailbox, and you have the count on the sent-items folder. If on the other hand you need to count the number of e-mails from a particular recipient, then you have to iterate all e-mails of all folders.

Comment: How about performing a search, based on the Sender name?

Answer (score -1):

This may be a long-shot, but have you thought about talking to the Exchange server directly via WebDAV? I've used the "WebDAV .NET for Exchange" before, it acts as a .NET wrapper over the WebDAV, so you don't need to understand the WebDAV part. The trial version if free.

A key advantage is that you don't need to connect to the exchange server using the same credentials as Outlook, so you could connect with an "admin" account and query other people's mailboxes without needing to grant that permission to the local user.

Here's a link to the site and the tutorials:
[IndependentSoft WebDAV .NET for Exchange](http://www.independentsoft.de/webdavex/tutorial/index.html?gclid=COe16dO5kqgCFUlkfAodii7gCw)

Comment: the Op mentions an Outlook addin, and the email received in Outlook can be other than Exchange too ; eg one can configure Outlook for a Gmail account too. Hence talking directly to the Exchange server is not a solution.